# Rails Render Layout Using File Not In Views/Layout to Support a Theme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, themes, render

Is it possible to use a layout file that is not in views/layout?

I would like users to be able to upload a theme which has a layout file and be able to use the uploaded and parsed file as their layout.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

## Don't do it!

You will open a big security hole, including [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), arbitrary code execution & private information disclosure.

Comment: That's a good point.  I'd parse the "layout files" before letting them be active.  I want to do something like Tumblr where people can submit there own themes.  Any idea on how this could be acheived?